# Delete rows using table partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I have a huge log table which is very busy in saving the user logs. My task is to schedule a job which keeps the last 3 days log or last 50k rows (whichever is greater) and deletes the rest. Shall this can be done through TABLE PARTITION.? I can't do this through DELETE statement which is very time expensive and stopping rows to be inserted. The table contains log_time as VARCHAR.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have any other way to get this please let me know.

Comment: May be it is ugly, but you can rename your table as Table_Histrory_20150129, then create new table and copy those 50k rows into it?

Comment: But why is your title shouting at us?

Comment: Why store log_time as varchar?  That requires double the space as datetime and complicates this task.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you this simple solution:

1. create every 3 days table named like `log-2015-01-28` and write all logs between `2015-01-28` - `2015-01-30` to this table
2. after `2015-01-30` create new table `log-2015-01-28-31` and write all new rows to it
3. DROP table `log-2015-01-28` after 2 days

I think it must work very fast

Answer (score 0):

> create trigger on insert
>
> while trigger check the spaceused of the table .
>
> if > 50k then delete the 'oldest row'

Comment: I think trigger is not good idea, because we get slowing down the `INSERT` operation